# DevTools failed to load sourceMap files , HTTP error : status code 403, net:: ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devtools

We have an application developed in reactjs, that application has suddenly started giving below warning , which is causing lot of latency issue in rendering the app.

> `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for abc.com/form/assets/css/main.prod.v4.079889.map: HTTP error: status code 403, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

What could be the root cause for this ?

Comment: The cause might be your app not producing sourcemap file or the file just cannot be accessed: https://httpstatuses.com/403

Comment: Building the react app should generate these files and put them in the `static` folder. Did you check the results of the build process? Does it produce the map files? Do they exist on the server in the location the browser says it's looking for them? Have you done *any* investigation of this issue yourself so far?

Comment: I want to confirm first, should we allow devTools to access those files in production ?

Comment: And if the browser is not able to find these files then how come the application is working ?

Comment: Regarding your first question: that's up to you. Those files are not necessary for your app to work. I would question if the waring is actually slowing down your app in the way you have described it. Have a read about what are the sourcemap files in general

Comment: When you build the app, webpack bundles all your stylesheets (and scripts) together into a single, compressed one. That map file allows you to use the browser's dev tools as if you still had multiple, nicely formatted CSS (and JS) files when it comes to showing errors and the like. 403 typically means "access denied", but the error doesn't fit that. Again, what's inside `/form/assets/css/` on the server...?

Comment: If somehow i stopped the devTools to work on production then i should not get this error, right